# Delete tag: 2008

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I think tag "2008" is not neccesary.

All the questions in tag 2008 reffer to windows server 2008 or sql 2008. Both of them already have their own tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, date tags. Generally artifacts of someone entering "windows server 2008" into the tag line. Time to die.

Answer (score 3):

KILL IT WITH FIRE!